# To count the occurrences of each year for each 'option' and 'Type',

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I have the following data frame:

```
d_f = pd.DataFrame({
'Type': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
'count': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one'],
2022: [0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],
2023: [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],
2024: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0],
2025: [1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
2026: [0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0.5],
'option': [0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]})
```

I am trying to count the occurrences of each year for each 'option' according to the values in "Type".

I used the following code:

```
table = d_f.pivot_table(index=['Type'], columns='option',aggfunc='count'
                                            ).fillna(0)
table
```

and this as well:

```
table = d_f.groupby(['option', 'Type'])[2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026].count()
table = table.unstack(level=0).fillna(0)
```

But unfortunately, both of them did not return the correct answer. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

The answer should be something like:

[image]

Comment: What should be the correct answer then? The group by operation seems correct.

Comment: How can 2022 / option 1.0 / bar be 3.0?

Comment: option contains values [0, 0.5, 1] and for these values and I would like to count the occurrences of thees values in the columns year.

Comment: @Adam sorry it's unclear, can you break down the number `3`?

Comment: Adam, if you have feedback for the answer you received, you should use the comments below that answer rather than making suggested edits.

Comment: 3 indicates the 'bar' 3 times appears in the year 2022. For this, I count how many 1s in the column 2022 with regard to 'bar'

Comment: yes but how come you aggregate ```bar``` without taking into account the options ?

Comment: @Adam OK, I think I got it, but it wasn't so clear, please check and let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you want something like:

```
(d_f.drop(columns='option')
    .melt(['Type', 'count'], var_name='year', value_name='option')
    .groupby(['Type', 'year', 'option'])['option'].count()
    .unstack('year', fill_value=0).unstack('option', fill_value=0)
)
```

Or:

```
df2 = (d_f.drop(columns='option')
          .melt(['Type', 'count'], var_name='year', value_name='option')
      )

out = pd.crosstab(df2['Type'], [df2['year'], df2['option']])
```

Output:

```
year   2022         2023         2024         2025         2026        
option  0.0 0.5 1.0  0.0 0.5 1.0  0.0 0.5 1.0  0.0 0.5 1.0  0.0 0.5 1.0
Type                                                                   
bar       0   0   3    0   0   3    2   0   1    0   1   2    1   1   1
foo       2   1   0    1   2   0    0   2   1    1   1   1    1   1   1
```

Comment: Sincerely, it's excellent, I didn't know how to use melt until now. Now it's done.

Comment: @LaurentB. Yes it's a very useful function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Provided dataframe

```
d_f
  Type count  2022  2023  2024  2025  2026  option
0  foo   one   0.0   0.0   0.5   1.0   0.0     0.0
1  foo   one   0.0   0.5   0.5   0.0   0.5     1.0
2  foo   two   0.5   0.5   1.0   0.5   1.0     0.0
3  bar   two   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.5   1.0     0.5
4  bar   one   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0     1.0
5  bar   one   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.5     0.5
```

```py
import pandas as pd

d_f = pd.DataFrame({
'Type': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
'count': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one'],
2022: [0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],
2023: [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1],
2024: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0],
2025: [1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
2026: [0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0.5],
'option': [0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]})

table = d_f.groupby(['option', 'Type']).nunique().drop('count', axis=1)
table = table.unstack(level=0).fillna('')

print(d_f)
```

```
table
       2022           2023           2024  ...      2025           2026          
option  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  ...  1.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.5  1.0
Type                                       ...                                   
bar          1.0  1.0       1.0  1.0       ...  1.0       2.0  1.0       2.0  1.0
foo     2.0       1.0  2.0       1.0  2.0  ...  1.0  2.0       1.0  2.0       1.0

[2 rows x 15 columns]
```

For visibility I used `fillna('')`

Comment: This returns the same results I have already with both commands above.

Comment: At least, do you have the same result like me ?

Comment: yes, I have the same results that you have had. Please try to run the commands above of mine.

Comment: I don't understand you have 3 occurrences for ```bar``` in 2022 in your result for option 1, if we refer to the provided dataframe ? Seems there is a problem with the expected result according to provided dataframe.

Comment: Alright, I would like to calculate the occurrences of 'bar' and 'foo' in each year, meaning: if 'bar' appears 2 times 0.5 in the column 2022, this means 'bar' should have the occurrence of 2 times in the year column 2022. The same goes for 0 and 1. This applies to 'foo' as well.

When we look at Column 2022, we can read that 'foo' has 2 times 0, and one time 0.5 and 'bar' has 3 ones (or 3 time appearance) in that column.

Comment: The last options column is useless and confused me. In addition Mozway give an excellent answer. Like you I am just learning on So. There are some so clever guys out there 8-). But excellent question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat` and a simple `groupby` + `value_counts`

```
>>> pd.concat([d_f.groupby('Type')[year].value_counts()
               for year in [2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026]], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

---

```
          2022  2023  2024  2025  2026
Type                                  
bar  0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   0.0     1
     0.5   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0     1
     1.0   3.0   3.0   1.0   2.0     1
foo  0.0   2.0   1.0   0.0   1.0     1
     0.5   1.0   2.0   2.0   1.0     1
     1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0     1
```